# QT queue fired connections

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

What is the best/most considrable way to queue **fired connections** in one thread to not freeze the gui?

E.g. I have a QGraphicsScene where I can freely move QGraphicsItem. I want to start a time consuming claculation with the current Item position. But one single calculation is fast enough to not recogize the gui freeze.

So, just connecting to `itemChange()` afte doing `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges, true);` is too expensive: the **GUI freezes** because of new calculations at every move.

---

I want to queue the connection to just fire, let's say every 500ms, not on every move. (Or after 500ms of no user input)

Comment: You might use two timers: `timer1` and `timer2`. When you move an item you restart `timer1`. When `timer1` is timed out, it starts `timer2`. When `timer2` is timed out it starts the calculations. When you move the item it also stops the `timer2`. Something like that.

Comment: I already thought about using one timer and somehow queueing the signals in a LIFO/FILO.
I'd pretend to start the time new every time the list gets pushed. And then just pop the list after the timer finished. -
But is't that bad practice to use a timer? Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer with a 500ms timeout, set up to run `expensiveCalculation` once and then stop.

```
QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
t->setInterval(500);
QObject::connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, t, &QTimer::stop);
QObject::connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, this, &expensiveCalculation);
```

Now connect the `itemChanged` signal to its `start` slot. This will start or restart the timer every time the signal is fired. If no new events appear for 500ms, the timer goes off and does `expensiveCalculation`.

```
QObject::connect(item, &QGraphicsItem::itemChanged, t, &QTimer::start);
```

Comment: Excactly what I was thinking. Is that good practice to use a timer? (Ignoging the fact that I asked about a certain time delay.)

Comment: Sure. Timers are cheap.

Comment: Note that this approach might be not optimal when you move an item slowly. You may have mouse lags.

Comment: @vahancho You mean that the `itemChanged` signal might not fire even though the mouse is moving?

Comment: @Botje, the situation when you move the mouse while `expensiveCalculation` still runs. If it runs in the same thread, the mouse event will not be processed.

Comment: Wouldn't those be queued by the underlying window system?

Comment: Yes, the gui still freezes when I grab an item while it calculates. And @Botje is right, the mouse movement is queued in the meantime. I guess I will have to try a lot to find an appropriate delay.

Comment: You could also do the expensive operation on a different thread (search for QFuture and QFutureWatcher) and keep the UI thread unblocked.

Comment: Yes the real calculation actually is in a different threat. The rather blocking part is the visualisation of that, and I obviously can't do that from another thread. In the future I optimize my colleague's implementation who did this...